# start\kill local EXE application with Node.js

Tags: node.js, process

I have a local node.js application in windows - is it possible to start \ kill local .EXE application and kill it in my code.

Is it possible? If so, I would be glad to see an example.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for very interesting question. I assume you mean killing your very own application?

Comment: Thanks for the +1 - but I mean to external process (other exe program that I have on the machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you planning to kill your very own node process, the process API exposes the [method exit()](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code), which is indeed a wrapper to the [C exit()](http://visionmedia.github.io/masteringnode/book.html#process-exit-) method. According to the docs, it takes a parameter to specify success or failure.

One very "interesting" thing, then, would be to implement a controller to stop your server. Something like this:

```
app.post('/stop/server/now', function(){
    process.exit(0);
});
```

**EDIT** To kill other processes, you simply need to know their pid (and have enough permission to kill other processes).

First, to get the pids, execute a command to do so. On Linux, this would be:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec("ps aux | grep 'process_to_kill' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'",
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec output: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Then, you pass these pids to the [process.kill() API](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal).